# ROM and RAM size of a binary file

Tags: c, memory, shared-libraries, ram, rom

I know that RAM size = Stack + HEAP at run time.

what about ROM? Is it BSS + text + R.O data? Can anyone confirm and explain the same?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It won't be 'classic' BSS, which must be writeable.  Anyway, those segment/section placement names all kinda depend on compler/linker configuration.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @Coder Could you elaborate about the platform for which you would like to have this answered? You ask about shared libraries but typical hosted platforms don't use ROM, so I'd like to know what RAM and ROM means for you.

Comment: Well, those sections have historic, weird names by default.  Executable code is 'text', (don't ask), actual read-only text and the like goes in 'rodata', BSS.stack are writeable, but only BSS needs initializing.   It's all Googleable.

Comment: @FUZxxl platform is linux, arch is ARM.

Comment: @Coder And what do you mean with “ROM?”

Comment: ROM will contain the code, a copy of all initialized data, and parameters for start and length of zero initialized data, plus register setup. Boot code in ROM will move the copy of initialized data into RAM, zero the part of RAM data as specified by parameters, setup the registers, then start the main code.